# Heroku won't accept needed URL argument to prevent MySql zeroTimeBehavior error

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I've developed a *Play/Scala* application that runs on my local *MySql*. But a needed database URL argument, `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` (Java TimeStamp) gets mangled by some further concatination of the URL that *Heroku* does and so my app can't get a connection to `ClearDB` (the Heroku MySql offering).

Here is my DB URL:

```
db.default.url="mysql://be32d43afc3cb7:c73c404d@us-cdbr-east-03.cleardb.com/heroku_6cf0eb306e78bc8?reconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
```

and the subsequent Heroku version that it transmogrifies:

```
JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-east-03.cleardb.com/heroku_6cf0eb306e78bc8?reconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
```

Something mysterious is going on with the `?` and `&` deliminators.

Heroku says the error is caused by:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'zeroDateTimeBehavior' only accepts values of the form: 'exception', 'round' or 'convertToNull'. The value 'convertToNull?useUnicode=yes' is not in this set.
```

So, is there some other way I can configure this argument? Without it, I get this error:

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[SQLException: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp]]
```

This strike a bell with anybody? Much thanks to anyone who can shed some light.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**
Heroku also concatenates several args to the DB URL that they provide users. Because of Heroku's use concatenation of "?" before their own set of args, attempting to add my own args to the DB URL will not work. However I found a different solution which seems to work equally well.

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

I put this in my table descriptions and it solved the problem of
    '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: I realize that Heroku is expecting a raw URL without any args to which it concatenates its own args. So the problem really is what other way can I handle the error: "Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp"? How else, besides the URL, can I pass the arg to MySql: zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull